# Is there a limit for the number of targets you can have in an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, product, targets

I'm planning to have different targets in a single Xcode project. Is there a limitation on the number of targets I can have? I tested this by creating 10 targets manually and didn't see a problem but I'd like to know if someone had a problem about this before.

Comment: No, i think there isnt any limit.. i once met a guy who made above 80 targets and his project was running without any problem. only thing was his xcode became Laggy.

Answer (score 0):

Targets alone don't have much weight.

The file references of the targets (e.g. source files to build) and dependencies tend to be set the logical limits. I have a project with over 100 targets. It's generally better to build things out by dependencies, where possible.